# Retrive the json value in laravel view

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-blade

In controller, I am retrieving a particular model from database.

```
$user = UserModel::find($id);
```

if I do `var_dump($user)` I get the following:

```
protected 'attributes' => 
array (size=14)
  'id' => int 1
  'email' => string 'superadmin@admin.com' (length=20)
  'password' => string '$2y$10$/T5qdWHjuXikhk14WqqwwuS7POmrOzmGzePkEapaiP4cPRZ3GLv9i' (length=60)
  'permissions' => string '{"superuser":1}' (length=15)
  'activated' => int 1
       .....
       .....
```

I am returning the data to the view

```
return View::make('users.modalPermissions', compact('user'));
```

In my view I can access the data like

```
{{$user->email}} //superadmin@admin.com
{{$user->permissions}} //{"superuser":1}
```

My concern is regarding `{{$user->permissions}}`, as right now I am getting string `{"superuser":1}` as output. How can I access its `key(superuser)` and `value(1)` in my view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the string is json use;

```
json_decode($user->permissions, true)['superuser'];
```

to access the superuser information. But i recommend you do all this within your controller before you send the data so instead of doing this you could do something like;

```
$user->permissions['superuser'];
```

To do this;

```
$user->permissions = json_decode($user->permissions, true);
```

This will go within your controller before you return the view you return with the user data.

Then within your view you can call the following;

```
$user->permissions['superuser']
```

Comment: You need the quotes too `json_decode($user->permissions)['superuser']`. And note that this syntax will only work on PHP 5.4 and above.

Comment: I have tried both of those and they don't work. json_decode($user->permissions)['superuser']; gives ´Cannot use object of type stdClass as array´ and $user->permissions['superuser']; gives Illegal string offset 'superuser'. I am on PHP version 5.4+.

Comment: Yes, that worked. But it seems rather a little ugly solution. How about the one you suggested from controller?

Comment: Now I can access the value as {{$user->permissions['superuser']}} in my view. Thanks.